# Selecting and using duplicate rows in a Pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, reformatting

I have the following data as part of a Pandas DataFrame, df::

```
  qsoName,filterID,aperMag 
0 PSOJ000,3,+19.284586
1 PSOJ007,2,+20.334393
2 PSOJ007,3,+20.226970
3 PSOJ007,4,+20.288778   
4 PSOJ007,5,+20.189209
5 PSOJ011,2,+21.037594
6 PSOJ011,4,+20.642813            
7 PSOJ011,5,+20.760576
```

and I'd like to pick out the different values of `df['aperMag']` for the one value of `df['qsoName']`, with -999.99999 being a default, e.g.

```
 PSOJ000,-999.99999,+19.284586,-999.99999,-999.99999
 PSOJ007,+20.334393,+20.226970,+20.288778,+20.189209
 PSOJ011,+21.037594,-999.99999,+20.642813,+20.760576
```

This feels like `df["qsoName"].duplicated()` should work, but the reformatting of the DataFrame is the other key part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.pivot('qsoName','filterID','aperMag').fillna(-999.99999)
```

Or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and parameter `fill_value`:

```
df = df.set_index(['qsoName','filterID'])['aperMag'].unstack(fill_value=-999.99999)
```

---

```
print (df)
filterID           2           3           4           5
qsoName                                                 
PSOJ000  -999.999990   19.284586 -999.999990 -999.999990
PSOJ007    20.334393   20.226970   20.288778   20.189209
PSOJ011    21.037594 -999.999990   20.642813   20.760576
```

Last if necessary:

```
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)
print (df)
   qsoName           2           3           4           5
0  PSOJ000 -999.999990   19.284586 -999.999990 -999.999990
1  PSOJ007   20.334393   20.226970   20.288778   20.189209
2  PSOJ011   21.037594 -999.999990   20.642813   20.760576
```

EDIT:

Problem is some data pairs (`qsoName`, `filterID`) are duplicated, so need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='qsoName',
                    columns='filterID', 
                    values='aperMag', 
                    fill_value=-999.99999, 
                    aggfunc='mean')
```

Comment: Nope; getting a "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" error.

Comment: @npross - So need aggregate values, because duplicates - use `df = df.pivot_table(index='qsoName',columns='filterID', values='aperMag', fill_value=-999.99999, aggfunc='mean')`

Comment: Btw, the actual .csv data file I'm using is at: https://github.com/d80b2t/StackOverflow/tree/master/54536518

Comment: Okay, the aggregate values thing seems to work. If you edit the answer above, I can tick this to close the question.

Comment: @npross - Done.